# Entity Framework DateTime defaults

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2005, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to automagically map a `DateTime.MinValue` to a null value in the data layer and vice-versa?

I am trying out EF6.  I want to eventually target SQL Server 2005 servers, so the `DATETIME2` type is something I want to avoid.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using nullable DateTime properties in Entity Framework to more clearly specify your intent.

Comment: That may be the way I end up going, but I've been struck with how similar EF6 is to a modern Fluent NHibernate instance, where this is quite doable, so I'm curious how far the similarities go.

Comment: EF does not support something like this through mapping/fluent API. You could override `SaveChanges()` and inspect/update entities on save but it would be more involved.

Comment: @Pawel if you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not support mapping min/max/specific values to null through mapping/fluent API. You could override `SaveChanges()` and inspect/update entities on save but it would be more involved

Answer (score 0):

There two way to solve it:

1. You can set Default Value=DateTime.MinValue for your datetime
   field in model editor.
2. You can set StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity for your datetime field in model editor and set default value for that field in SQL table.